# RTDB Rules - only updatable before time (time that is referenced in other path)

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have two paths:

```
/lotteries
----/uniqueID001
-------/active: true
-------/choicesCutoff
---------/1: 11th August 2020 10:41 AM
---------/2: 11th August 2020 11:41 AM


/tickets
----/uniqueID0234
-------/lottery: uniqueID001
-------/choices
---------/1: 'initial choice'
---------/2: 'initial choice'
```

I need to create a database rule so that people cant change their choice after the cutoff.

i'm currently using **update** like so `ref('/tickets/uniqueID0234}/choices').update({1: 'new choice'})`
and have client side logic for disabling changes after the cutoff. This works fine but if the user changes their device time, they will be able to change their ticket.

How do I write a rule that references the lottery id and the associated cut off; to disable making updates after the cutoff?

*(Each choice has a different cutoff)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you stored the cutoff values as timestamp, that'd be something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "tickets": {
      "$ticketid": {
        "choices": {
          "$choiceid": {
            ".write": "root.child('lotteries').child(
                         data.parent().parent().child('lottery').val()
                       ).child($choiceid).val() > now"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In here:

- The `data.parent().parent().child('lottery')` is the `lottery` of the current ticket.
- We then build a path from the `root` of the database to the data for *that* lottery.
- We look up the current `$choiceid` under the data for that lottery.
- And finally compare *that* value with the current time on the server.

There might be some small mistakes in the code, hence the step-by-step explanation of how it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didnt even really consider chaining parent()'s i'll give that a go now!